# TensorBoard - Download the graph PNG through code

Tags: tensorboard

I can view on TensorBoard the computation graph I have constructed and through the browser I can also download its PNG.

Is there a way to download the graph through code (without opening the browser)?

I have tried to inspect the HTML page, but unfortunately there is no direct link I can copy.